# ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)

Tags: python, django, sqlite

**ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later**

I met with this problem at the django project, mismatching version for the sqlite3 and the django. this occurs at the centos7 env, and I also want a convenient solution that works in the container env.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by upgrading my version of sqlite3 using this command:

```
cd ~ && wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3320100 && ./configure && make && make install
```

I am using ElasticBeanstalk for my setup, so I added a .config file to the .ebextensions folder and put this in it:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "/usr/local/lib"
commands:
  01_upgrade_sqlite:
    command: "cd ~ && wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3320100 && ./configure && make && make install"
```

Many thanks to [Bejür](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903516/7933218) for adding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable here in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, upgrading sqlite with [kloddant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62815674/7933218)'s instructions helped only partially. SQLite was installed, but python was still referring to the old sqlite version.

An additional step to fix this issue was setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"`

Add it to `.ebextensions/*.config`

```yaml
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "/usr/local/lib"
```

Comment: Did this really work? I've tried this as well as adding a command `command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`, but I keep getting the error `deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher`.

Comment: Something must have changed with Elastic Beanstalk.  My answer worked back then, but now it stopped working until I added this bit from you.  Thank you so much!  I'll incorporate your answer into mine for future viewers.

Answer (score -1):

You have an outdated version of SQLite,you can try this:

```
python -m pip install -U sqlite
```

Comment: I’m sorry I tried,  but this doesn't work wor me. thanks all the same.

Answer (score -4):

I now find a usable solution: change the version of Django from 'Django==3.0.4' to 'Django==2.1.8' and it worked.

> pip install django==2.1.8 -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/

Comment: Downgrading Django, while it might work, is not really a great option and is at best a short-term fix.

Comment: It‘s not, but with time restriction. Expect your superior solution.

Comment: I've posted it.  However, if I had not found a way, I would recommend using a conventional database instead of sqlite.